# Can't log into Google Play Store or my Google account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google, google-play-services

Through a series of mishaps, I deleted Google Play Services, Google+ and probably many other apps. I did a factory reset, but it did not bring back my missing apps. My phone was rooted and I used Titanium to delete them, not knowing services was needed. Now whenever I hit Google store and need to log in I can't because it says:

> Couldn't sign it. There was a problem communicating with Google servers. Try again later.

I am really confused as to what to do. I cannot download from online directly because it still wants me to put my Google account and I get the same message.

Any help or is my phone just done at this point? I have an android LGMS323.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that sure looks like you have messed your device really well, I would suggest the better option would be downloading the stock ROM and flashing it over your device anyway there's also another option which you can use like get the apk file of the apps from sites like Android Police.

[Google PlayStore](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-0-38-apk/),
[Google PlayServices](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-6-5-88-1599915-836-apk/),
[Google+](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google/google-4-7-1-79583515-apk/)

Install then over your device and I guess rest of the app can be easily downloaded over the Google PlayStore.

Answer (score -1):

I would just recommend installing the zip file of the google apps usually called `gapps.zip`. You can find the corresponding files for download at [goo.im](https://goo.im/); make sure to pick the one matching your device's Android version. Then copy it to your device's SD card, boot into recovery, chose to "install from zip", select the file – and once it's flashed you should be done, simply reboot.

Comment: Can you edit this and add a link to the gapps package for the OP, and note there is a version of gapps for each Andriod release.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but thanks to the bot bringing it back up, figured I would post incase others have this issue.

Assuming you have a custom recovery(since the device is rooted), open up settings > about device > And find out what version of android you are running, then head over to https://basketbuild.com/gapps and download the package for your version of android. Then flash via recovery. It will add the google apps for ya, then you should be able to get back in to the play store.

Edit: Goo.im closed since this post was last posted. Just and FYI for those looking at this